# Bash Build Error: No rule found config.status

Tags: bash, makefile

I am currently using the following version of make

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

I downloaded the code of Bash-4.3 from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/ into the directory

```
F:\Users\MyUname\Desktop\bash-4.3
```

I already have an existing bash~3.1 shell installed as a part of the GitHub for windows package which I am now using to build bash-4.3 (the path of the above bash 3.1 shell is in the PATH env var)

Now, following the instructions given in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Basic-Installation, I have performed the following steps. (my parent shell is windows powershell)

```
[powershell prompt]> cd F:\Users\MyUname\Desktop\bash-4.3
F:\Users\MyUname\Desktop\bash-4.3> bash
bash.exe"-3.1$ pwd
/f/Users/Arjun/Desktop/bash-4.3
bash.exe"-3.1$ ./configure
...
...
...
<output of ./configure>
...
...
...
bash.exe"-3.1$ make
...
...
...
making lib/intl/libintl.a in ./lib/intl
make[1]: Entering directory 'f:/Users/Arjun/Desktop/bash-4.3/lib/intl'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/f/Users/Arjun/Desktop/bash-4.3/config.status', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'f:/Users/Arjun/Desktop/bash-4.3/lib/intl'
Makefile:648: recipe for target 'lib/intl/libintl.a' failed
make: *** [lib/intl/libintl.a] Error 1
```

A quick check indicates that the file `config.status` indeed exists at the above specified location. Yet `make` seems to be bent on finding a rule to create `config.status`

On looking into the source code, the line(s) that appear to be source of this error are.

```
Makefile: $(srcdir)/Makefile.in $(top_builddir)/config.status
    cd $(top_builddir) && $(SHELL) ./config.status
```

Is there any step that i am missing, or is this a bug in `make` or `bash` for that matter?

Comment: I suspect a Windows-Unix path mismatch problem. make enters directory `f:...` while it searches for a file named `/f/...`. This inconsistency is probably the origin of your problem.

Comment: I guessed as much. I tried then to build it using the MSYS environment. however it appears that a few linux/POSIX (not sure) specific header files such as pwd.h are not provided by MSYS / MINGW. it appears that there is no effective way of natively compiling the bash src. I have moved on to using cygwin instead. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Based on the comment above, I'm recommending this be closed as cannot reproduce.